# discord.js how to make it so a bot goes onto a website api and sends back whatever the website said

Tags: api, discord, discord.js

Hey so im coding a discord bot (discord.js) and I have a website im trying to make it so when you say a command it goes onto my websites api then sends whatever the website said back into server any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know a LOT of people have this question...
I found a video that seems to be in your best interest. I haven't watched it all the way through as it is pretty lengthy, but in this video, he explains how to make a dashboard, hosted off your own computer, but it is also do-able in a regular VPS, not sure about something like Heroku...

Video Tutorial Link:     https://youtu.be/h0iTrmuphYs